# Force Windows 2000 Server to shut down using a Script rather than show "safe to turn off"

Tags: windows, hardware, windows-server-2000, scripting

I am trying to use a script (kindly provided by Evan Anderson in [another thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/160274/run-shutdown-script-on-a-domain-server-to-shut-down-windows-2000-servers-in-a-dif)) to shut down a couple of Windows 2000 Servers which run our Cisco Unity system, in the event that our environmental monitoring software detects a problem such as a air con failure.

The script is:-

> net use \x.x.x.x\ipc$
>   /user:administrator password  shutdown
>   -s -t 10 -f -m \x.x.x.x  met ise \x.x.x.x\ipc$ /delete

When the script runs windows logs off but then comes up with a message telling me "it is now safe to turn off your computer" screen.  The weird thing is that I can shut down the computer using start  Shutdown and when I do so the server powers off so I know that the hardware is capable of being shut off.

I have checked in the BIOS and advanced power management is switched on. I have looked in the control panel but there is no entry for power management.

I have added the REG_SZ value "PowerdownAfterShutdown" in "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" and set it to "1" but still get the same behaviour.

Since the whole point is to prevent the servers from frying if the room over heats I really need to get them to power off.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Many thanks

Shaz

Comment: what service pack is your server 2000 server?

Comment: Service Pack 4 (build 2195)

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen this article [kb810903](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/810903)?

It lists these possible causes:

- Your computer supports the Advanced Power Management (APM) feature, but the Advanced Configuration and Power Interface (ACP)-compliant basic input/output system (BIOS) is not configured correctly to permit the operating system to turn off the power supply.
- During an upgrade of the operating system, Windows does not detect that the computer is ACPI-compliant.
- An OEM device driver or service is installed on your computer that is preventing the computer from correctly shutting down.
- Your computer is not ACPI-compliant.

The article suggests several possible solutions depending on the cause.

Comment: I have had a look at the kb article, however if there was a hardware problem, or a BIOS issue would it not also result in the "safe to shut down" message being shown when I simply use start --> shutdown?  

The PC will power off I choose shut down from the OS.  Just not when I use the scirpt.

Comment: I have installed PSShutdown onto the call managers and the domain server that needs to run the script.  

Calling PSShutdown from the script works to shut down and power off the Windows 2000 server.  I don't know why this works to power off when the normal shutdown command won't but this seems to be the best way round the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed PSShutdown onto the call managers and the domain server that needs to run the script. Calling PSShutdown from the script works to shut down and power off the Windows 2000 server.

I don't know why this works to power off when the normal shutdown command won't but this seems to be the best way I can find around round the problem.

[More info on psshutdown can be found here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897541.aspx)